# how to check that a parametric equation represents a spherical surface?

Tags: geometry, parametric, spheres

i have parametric equation of an unknown surface $S(u,v)$: $x=f(u, v)$,  $y=g(u,v)$ and $z=h(u,v)$, where $u$ and $v$ are two independent variables.

How can I check whether it's a sphere or not?

my attempt:

i defined a general function:

$S=x^2+y^2+z^2$

I know that the value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ will be equal to the square of radius i.e.$R^2$ at every point $(x,y,z)$ on a sphere. Therefore to consider all the points on a sphere, if i calculate maximum and minimum values of $S=x^2+y^2+z^2$ they must always be equal for a sphere. so I can write a general condition to check where it is a sphere or not

1. if max$(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ $=$ min$(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, it is a spherical surface
2. if max$(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ $\ne$ min$(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, it is not spherical surface

Is my above condition will work to check whether it's a spherical surface or not for any arbitrary input of parametric equations, $x=f(u, v)$,  $y=g(u,v)$ and $z=h(u,v)$?

i have checked that my above condition fails to distinguish between a spherical surface say $x=5\sin u\cos v$, $y=5\sin u\sin v$ and $z=5\cos u$  and a toroidal surface say $x=(15+4\cos u)\cos v$, $y=(15+4\cos u)\sin v$ and $z=4\sin u$. but I don't know why it becomes true for a toroidal surface too. initially I thought that above condition is true only for a spherical surface only but i found that it's also true for a toroidal surface.

please suggest me any generic condition to exactly check if parametric equation $S(u,v)$ is spherical surface or not for 100% certainty. thanks

Comment: Why can't you just check if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is a constant? Also, the (max,min) values for a torus with the equation you have given is (361,121) (assuming $u,v\in{\mathbb R}$) which are clearly not equal. I think your condition is fine. PS - if your condition holds or if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is a constant all you can say is that your surface forms part of a sphere. Whether the entire sphere is covered by your parametric equation has to be separately checked by looking at the range of your functions $f$, $g$ and $h$.

Comment: i am writing a matlab program so how can a function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ be equated to a constant? can you please help with this?